# Uno Platform on WSL: Errors in unchanged template

Tags: cross-platform, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uno, wsl-2

I'm attempting to build the Uno project template with Linux support, using WSL (Ubuntu 20.04), following the [official guide](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-with-linux.html).

Unfortunately, I always get an error running the Skia GTK project template:
`DllNotFoundException: Gtk: libgtk-3-0.dll, libgtk-3.so.0, libgtk-3.0.dylib, gtk-3.dll`

I tried adding `libgtk-3-0.dll`'s folder to the Windows `PATH`, but this didn't help.  Then I tried installing libgtk-3 in WSL, but it just changed the error to `Can't open display :0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Skia.Gtk backend expects a running X Window server to connect to.

The guide suggests installing [vcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/), an X11 server for Windows
You'll need to start the server in "Multiple windows" mode, starting with "no client" mode.